# open native iOS app from browser, how?

Tags: ios, html

I would like to know how I will open the native ios App Facebook or Twitter fromout the webbrowser (html5) when an iOS user clivks on the link for Like us in Facebook.

Does anybody know how to refer to this native iOS app, and what the link/redirect command is tot the Check in page in this App?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you should have an index.html file. Open this using firefox or google chrome browser, and then you can inspect the elements.

If your app does has many html pages then that is not good programming practice. Usually with jquery mobile each page is a div and you can animate elements using jquery, ajax, json and whichever javascript library you need to reference